# Apify crawler with more than 2 clickable element

Tags: javascript, apify

I am trying to create an apify crawler, which has multiple clickable element. First click is to paginate, second click to visit each result, third is to visit a section of each result to extract more information.

```
function pageFunction(context) {
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    if (context.request.label === 'category'|| context.request.label === 'detail') {
        context.skipLinks();

        var result = {
            item_name: $('name').text(),
            categories: $('.categories').text(),
            email: $('email').text(),
            kvk: $('kvk').text()
        };
        return result;
    } else {
        context.skipOutput();
    }
}
```

The first 2 clicks are happening, it paginates and visits the results and extract first 3 values : `item_name, categories and email`

The fourth value : kvk is not returned. I think either the third click is not happening or the code I used have some errors. Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: What is the target website and what are the PseudoURLs you're using?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems can the `context.skipLinks()` a function that prevents any new enqueued pages. Also, did you check all the selectors in the developer console? For debugging I would advise you to log the content of the page so you know it loaded. First, you need to find the source of the problem.

ONe side note, I would advice you to start developing is our modern [web-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper). Crawler platform is no longer maintained and may perform worse for some cases.

Comment: I checked, its not detecting the 3rd click(url)